# gbs build --incremental vs --include-all

Tags: build

what is the differences belows?
If I modify source code(did not commit, yet)

1. gbs build -A armv7l --include-all
2. gbs build -A armv7l --incremental
3. gbs build -A armv7l --include-all --incremental

I do not understand the differences between incremental and include-all options, clearly.

Answer (score 1):

option 1 with build your source with all committed as well uncommitted changes

option 2 builds incrementally ( meaning if the build fails in between and then you make some changes, the next build will not start afresh but from the last build point) . This has some other conditions like changes in MACRO or header files where complete build will happen.

option 3 is a combination of option 1 and option 2